# An easy, seemingly, parametrization problem

Tags: calculus, parametrization

The ellipse $$x^2/4^2+y^2/7^2=1$$

can be drawn with parametric equations. Assume the curve is traced clockwise as the parameter increases.

If $$x=4\cos t$$

Find $y$

Clearly this is a  parametrization we can relate to the identity $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$, so the answer should be $y=7\sin t$. This gives then

$$\frac{x^2}{4^2}+\frac{y^2}{7^2}=1=\frac{4^2\cos^2}{4^2}+\frac{7^2\sin^2}{7^2}=1$$

But this is wrong, although it seems so apparently natural. I suspect it has to do with the direction. What is the error here?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider reversing time.

Comment: (minus t that is?) Thanks for that!

Comment: After simplification by $4^2$ and $7^2$, $(\cos t)^2 + (\sin t)^2 = 1$ would be wrong ?

Comment: Yes, negating $t$ is what they meant: the issue comes from the required direction, which you’re currently doing the opposite of